# cancel ASIHTTP request

Tags: iphone

I used ASIHTTP request to access web html page.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]];
[request setTag:selectTag];
[request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
[request setCachePolicy:ASIAskServerIfModifiedCachePolicy | ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy]; 
[request setCachePolicy:ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy];
[request setDelegate:self];


[request startAsynchronous];
```

If I navigate from an ViewController to another.

Is it possible to cancel this async http request if it has not yet triggered 'requestFinished'?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following method is present with ASIHttpRequest, you can use it to cancel the request -

```
- (void)cancel {
        [self performSelector:@selector(cancelOnRequestThread) onThread:[[self class] threadForRequest:self] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];    
}
```

You can call this method-

```
[request cancel];
```